# Python def statement parameter calling

Tags: python, function, parameters

```
 def rec():
    usr = input('Enter Name : ')
    pwd = input('Enter Password : ')
    return usr , pwd

def show():
    c = rec()
    print(c.usr , c.pwd)

show()
```

error -
print(c.usr , c.pwd)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'usr'

its just example , i want to know how can we pass values of one def function to other def function , like if i get values in def rec() and show the values in def show()
P.S : Can you please show me how to do this in comment as i am just beginner, Thanks in Advance

Comment: you return the value in the function.

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `rec()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but to do that you need to return something from your function that you called.

```
def rec():
    usr = input('Enter Name : ')
    pwd = input('Enter Password : ')
    return 10 # just an example to show that you need to return something here so that `c` can receive that value
def show():
    c = rec() # `c` will receive the value that you return from `rec()`
    print(c.usr , c.pwd)
    
show()
```

For your question from comment, the code should be like:

```
def rec():
    usr = input('Enter Name : ')
    pwd = input('Enter Password : ')
    return usr, pwd  # you returned two values
def show():
    c, d = rec()  # as you returned two values, you also need to receive them
    print(c , d)  # you values are in `c` and `d`, and there is nothing like `c.usr` here, so use only `c` and `d`
    
show()
```

Output:

```
Enter Name : shahin
Enter Password : 123
shahin 123
```

Comment: @Karan Verma i hope you got it now

Comment: Yes , i tried to return the input which i have taken from user like usr and pwd and returned but its showing AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'usr' , i updated my code in question

Comment: @KaranVerma i have added another code in my answer, have a look, hope now it is clear

Comment: Bro Thank you so much it works :) , Kudos to our coding brotherhood and you :)